# How can I retrieve data attached to an Eddystone-URL?

Tags: android, eddystone, google-beacon-platform, eddystone-url

I'm trying to experiment with Eddystone and Nearby messages in Android. I registered an Eddystone-UID with the [Proximity Beacon API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/guide) and attached some data. Then in my app I used the samples from the [Nearby Messages API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview) to retrieve it and everything seems to be working fine.

Since I want to use Eddystone-URL and a website for casual use, but offer the possibility of downloading an app, I was trying to use only the Eddystone-URL, and attach some data to it, so I can have additional information in the app.

I did the same steps as for the Eddystone-UID, but my app  doesn't see any message. The beacon seems registered, and the data attached to it, but the app it's not receiving anything.

Am I missing something? Is this not supported?

Comment: Are you registering something with setResultCallback ?? I think in our experiments here, we need to have that set to see some results.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that with the exact same code I can see data from an Eddystone-UID but not form a Eddystone-URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attachments you describe only work for Eddystone-UID. The whole purpose of the Eddystone-URL is to be based on the web, so this means not using any centralized servers(other than your web page). The URL just points you to a website. If you want data 'attached' to that URL, you would use web technologies to do that, e.g. have the data in your markup/as an additional web page/etc.

Edit: I believe you want to have the best of both worlds: the URL beacon for the simple web page and a UID for your app to have additional data. That's exactly why Eddystone has multiple frame times, just have a beacon that broadcasts both a URL and a UID.

Comment: Ho can you have a beacon that broadcasts both Eddystone-URL and Eddystone-UID ? (As far as I can see Estimotes are not able to do that)